# Android keeps thumbnails for deleted images and they appear when I request them, but original files dont

Tags: android, gallery, thumbnails

In my application I obtain image thumbnails from the device to show in my custom gallery from the MediaStore

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSORLOADER_THUMBS, null, this);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSORLOADER_REAL, null, this);

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int cursorID, Bundle arg1) {
    CursorLoader cl = null;

    ArrayList<String> img = new ArrayList<String>();
    switch (cursorID) {

    case CURSORLOADER_THUMBS:
        img.add(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        break;
    case CURSORLOADER_REAL:
        img.add(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cl = new CursorLoader(application, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img.toArray(new String[img.size()]), null, null, null);
    return cl;
}


private String getPathOfThumbnailById(Context context, int id) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[] { "" + id }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String fullPath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        return fullPath;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But if the user goes to a folder and deletes an image, Android doesnt delete the corresponding thumbnail so the gallery app keeps showing the thumbnail, user clicks on it, and no image is found.

Comment: Who is deleting the picture? Your app? The Gallery? Other app?

Comment: User deletes the image from somewhere else (some file explorer app for instance)

Comment: But android doesnt delete the corresponding thumbnail, so the thumbnail is still visible in MY app, but when user clicks on it, they dont get an image (cuz its been deleted)

Comment: Yes. What if user deletes an image using Gallery app?

Comment: The thumbnail that the system has created for it, remains undeleted and my app gets all thumbnails and shows them, which includes the thumbnail for the deleted image :(

Comment: Hard to believe if the user uses the Gallery app. Ok now `getPathOfThumbnailById()`. Do you use it? How? What does it return for a thumbnail from which the file is deleted?

Comment: It returns the path to the thumbnail

Comment: To the thumbnail? Not to the original file? Please give an example of such a path.

Comment: Sorry, it actually returns the path to the original file.

Comment: Very fine!!! but you did not tell for what you use it. But now that you know that you can use it to check with `File.exists()` if it is not deleted and not show it's thumbnail in your app then. Or change the thumbnail to your own 'deleted' icon.

Answer (score 0):

just put this code in **onResume()** so that when user leave your app for deleteing the image and after deleting that image user will come back to your app and your onReume() call and your app will refresh images.

Comment: As I said, Android doesnt delete the corresponding thumbnail image from the device, and my app gets the thumbnails which the system prepares when a new image is added to the device, so it always shows thumbnails to images who dont exist anymore